# Jquery, matching values without an exact match

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a working jquery code block where I'm taking the value from an html input and checking it against json values for a match.

It currently works if there's an exact match, so in the example below, I'd have to fully type 123 or 155 to get a result, but I want to get this to where typing '1' would show both and the like (basically look for matches without strings being fully typed or exact), like a standard autocomplete.

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var stores=[{
  "id": "123",
  },{
  "id": "155"
  }
];

function searchStores() {
  var foundStores = [];
  var value = document.getElementById('ss').value;

  console.log(value);

  if(value){
    stores.forEach(function (store,index) {
      var id = store.id;
      console.log(id);
      if(id == value){
        foundStores.push(store);
      };
    });
  }else{
    foundStores = stores;
  }
  console.log(foundStores);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ss" type="text" name="locationSearch" placeholder="search" style="border-radius:18px; padding:4px; width: 80%;" />
```

Comment: [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: @freedomn-m I've tried replacing my match with that before and I get that indexOf is not a function ```// if(id == value){
          //   foundStores.push(store);
          // };
          if(store.indexOf(value) !=-1){
            foundStores.push(store);
          }```

Comment: `store` is your object, so should be `store.id.indexOf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
if (id == value) {
```

does an equality comparison, so the values must match exactly.  As your `id` is a string rather than a number, you can use [string indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if (id.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
```

newer (current) versions of browsers could also use [string includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
if (id.includes(value)) {
```

Updated snippet (with an event handler to see it working):

```js
var stores = [{
  "id": "123",
}, {
  "id": "155"
}];

function searchStores() {
  var foundStores = [];
  var value = document.getElementById('ss').value;

  //console.log(value);

  if (value) {
    stores.forEach(function(store, index) {
      var id = store.id;
      //console.log(id, store, index);
      if (id.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
        foundStores.push(store);
      };
    });
  } else {
    foundStores = stores;
  }
  console.log(foundStores);
};

$("#ss").on("input", function() {
  searchStores();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="ss" type="text" name="locationSearch" placeholder="search" style="border-radius:18px; padding:4px; width: 80%;" />

<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are trying to achieve is to get your `stores` array and filter it by the text you type.
For that purpose, I suggest you use array `filter` method which iterates the whole array and returns a new array that satisfy some condition - in your case, the `id` contains the text you are typing

```js
var stores = [{
  "id": "123",
}, {
  "id": "155"
}];

function searchStores(event) {
  var text = event.target.value;
  var resultStores = stores.filter(store => store.id.includes(text));
  console.log(resultStores)
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input oninput="searchStores(event)" type="text" name="locationSearch" placeholder="search" style="border-radius:18px; padding:4px; width: 80%;"/>
```

Comment: Gave a +1 for use of `.filter`, but your snippet doesn't work for pasting, eg copy "1", clear, paste and it gives `[]`.  Probably `event.data`, but the code after that works well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I fixed it by changing `event.data` with `event.target.value`